# ElasticSearch .Net Nest issue with configuring indexSettings

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use the .Net client Nest 6.2 for ES.
I am trying to configure the default settings for number of shards and replicas.
this is the code I found online:
[using index settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/update-settings.html)

```
var indexName= "indexName";
var client = this.ConnectedClient;
var settings = new IndexSettings();
settings.NumberOfReplicas = 1;
settings.NumberOfShards = 5;    
client.CreateIndex(indexName, settings);
```

but the last line is raising a compilation error:

> cannot convert from Nest.INdexSettings to
>   System.Func

Answer (score 1):

There are two CreateIndex calls available in NEST but neither take an IndexSettings object. See here for details https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/02bdf28788e657cffc253598d7766820f9eed62e/src/Nest/Indices/IndexManagement/CreateIndex/ElasticClient-CreateIndex.cs

You can use the fluent syntax to do this in a much cleaner way

```
client.CreateIndex(indexName, i => i.Settings(s => s 
.NumberOfShards(5) .NumberOfReplicas(1)))
```

Comment: thank you. How do I add the object itself to the index?

Comment: Which object are we talking about? If the document, then use the BulkAll call if you have multiple docs.